# Using sleep() in game loop makes delta time unstable

Tags: c++, sfml, game-loop

I'm writing a game loop with sfml. When I don't make it sleep, time elapsed for each loop iteration is ~1ms. But when I add sleep(sleepTime) suddenly dt is high. I restart dt at the beginning of the loop but it seems that it adds last sleep time to it. What causes it?

```
sf::Clock clock;
float dt;
sf::Time sleepTime = sf::milliseconds(0);

while(m_Window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Time elapsed = clock.restart();
    dt = elapsed.asMilliseconds();

    cout << "Elapsed: " << dt;

    sf::Event event;

    while(m_Window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                m_Window.close();
                break;
        }
    }

    sleepTime = sf::milliseconds(16 - dt);

    float time = sleepTime.asMilliseconds();
    cout << "\tSleep time: " << time << endl;

    if(sleepTime >= sf::Time::Zero)
    {
        sf::sleep(sleepTime);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Shit." << endl;
    }
```

Without sleep: https://aww.moe/sn1z0a.png

With sleep: https://aww.moe/7seof1.png

Comment: The sleep causes it. Why are you sleeping?

Comment: Because I want to establish constant game speed. I'm using this: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ as guide.

Comment: And I know that sleep() is not super accurate. But I restart dt at the beginning of the loop, why sleep time is added to dt?

Comment: sleep is not going to establish anything like a constant game speed. That is the nature of time-sharing OSes.

Comment: It is unclear to me - what kind of output do you expect? You are polling your clock once for each iteration, which includes a sleep. So why shouldn't the sleep time be included in this reading? Perhaps you mean to poll the clock again before calculating `sleepTime`?

Comment: So is this enough? https://gist.github.com/Glamhoth/c10685004931f9fa8e27a63861240077

Comment: What operating system is this running on? It appears that sf::sleep() is based on a 64hz timer == 15.625 ms per tick. In the case of Windows, the tick rate can be increased to 1000hz == 1 ms per tick using [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) . With Windows XP, a windows Sleep(1) can take up to nearly 2ms. For Windows 7, it will take 1 ms. I don't know about Windows Vista. I have example code to run a thread at a fixed frequency, but it uses Windows API.

Comment: @rcgldr SFML uses the high precision timer (QueryPerformanceCounter), so resolution should be smaller than 1ms on any Windows machine running an up to date build.

Comment: @Mario - My prior comment was about sf:sleep() function. QueryPerforanceCoutner is high precision, but its timer doesn't generate any interrupts so it can't be used for sf::sleep() or windows Sleep().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do – limiting the game to a specific framerate – is already built into SFML. Just call `sf::Window::setFrameRateLimit()` with your intended framerate as parameter and you're set. It's also possible to use vertical synchronization (by using `sf::Window::setVerticalSyncEnabled()`) to limit the number of frames/updates, although it's often considered a bad idea, since the game would also slow down if the target machine can't render at the desired framerate (or speed up for high end screens running at 120 or 140Hz).

However, you'll typically want to disconnect your game updates from your frame rate so the game doesn't slow down, even if the current machine can't update the screen fast enough.

The basic approach using SFML will typically look like this (this is from memory, so might include bugs or typos):

```
sf::Clock updateTimer; // Clock to monitor the time passed
sf::Time passedTime; // Accumulated game time
const sf::Time frameTime(sf::milliseconds(10)); // intended time per frame; here: 10ms

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        // Event handling
    }

    // First add the time passed
    passedTime += updateClock.restart();

    unsigned int numUpdates = 0; // Count the updates done

    // As long as enough time passed, do an update
    // Up to a specific maximum to avoid problems, e.g.
    // the main thread was blocked or can't catch up
    while (passedTime >= frameTime) {

        if (numUpdates++ < 10) {
            // Do your game update here
        }

        // Subtract the time we've "handled"
        passedTime -= frameTime;
    }

    window.clear();
    // Draw your game here
    window.display();
}
```

The usage of `numUpdates` might not be clear at first, but just imagine a situation where the machine is barely able to run the desired 100 updates per second. If you're 20 updates behind (some hick-up or whatever) the machine will never be able to catch up again properly, causing heavy stuttering or the game becoming unresponsive.

Comment: @Glamhoth Don't restart the timer a second time (at the end). Otherwise you're losing the time it took you to draw everything.